# Imitate Paper Form with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-experience

Is there a way I can draw a Input Box with CSS, which has the background of a paper link grid box.

Something like this,

[image: http://oi42.tinypic.com/2zq9zkh.jpg]

When the user enters the data, the the cursor moves from one box to the next.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do this, but you can't simply describe what you want and expect the community to do the work for you.  Show us an indication that you've made an effort to write code for this and we'll help as much as you need.

Answer (score 2):

Should be possible. Use a monospace font, combined with the `background`, `line-height` and `letter-spacing` CSS properties. Experiment!

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CmnK8/).

Comment: To just flush this out more: the background image would be the boxes pattern. The image could be one C shaped box with a repeat-x. Monospace fonts have the same character widths on every letter (otherwise normal fonts have different widths; eg 'i' vs 'M'). The letter-spacing would help you fine-tune the space between letters to fit in your background image. The experiment will be changing the background image to fit perfectly! Good luck!

Comment: Tuning the background to the font width could get messy, unless you know the exact font metrics. Can you even guarantee them to be cross-browser and cross-machine consistent?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think Courier is safe, and defining in pixels should be safe. You never know, though.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of one input field you could use 25 like in the image! :D

Comment: ... and a lot of coding. Nice idea (I also thought of that), but I prefer Alex' solution ;-) (didn't downvote)

Comment: I prefer the other solution too, but this solution is literally how those paper ones work; which is kind of silly when you think about it. Who are they to say how much space I should take to write a letter?

Comment: Come to think of it, tuning the background to the font width could get messy. Yours is merely quite a bit of coding. +1

Comment: Sounds like you're more of a coder than Photoshopper. If I didn't just have a baby 2 days ago I'd offer to help with the bg image. Offer a designer a fancy coffee and they'll do just about anything for you ;)

Comment: You're still assuming the font metrics are the same on every machine and browser. They're not in general, and I don't think they are in case of any monospace font.

Comment: Even if you're explicit on px size? Multiple inputs will likely be a pain to validate / form into usable data on the backend.

Comment: The `font-size` defines the font height (or, some metric thereof - not even the count of non-white rows of some specific letter). The font width is defined by the font, and kerning kills any chance of cross-browser rendering. Maybe if the font had integer pixel-width for the kerning _and_ letters themselves, there would be a chance for cross-browser consistent _widths_. Don't even think about consistent _rendering_.

Comment: Not sure there's a perfect solution.  Whichever route one chooses, if the user chooses to zoom in, it all goes out the window!

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a background with css and choose a monotype font. Here is a short solution.

some css:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<style>
input {
    /* background grid */
    background: white;
    background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(left, 
        white 0px,      white 20px,     black 21px,     white 22px,
                        white 40px,     black 41px,     white 42px);
    border: 1px solid black; border-right: 0;

    /* magic width */
    width: 252px;

    /* font font font ... */
    font: normal 2em/1em 'Cutive Mono', serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;

    /* not really important */
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
}
</style>
```

and some html

```
<input type="text" value="hallo welt"/>
```

**// EDIT:**
For repeating-linear-gradient take a look to caniuse.com (http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-repeating-gradients) and add generally support without vendor tag.

```
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(left, 
        white 0px,      white 20px,     black 21px,     white 22px,
                        white 40px,     black 41px,     white 42px);
```